Cohomology Ring Calculation Query
I am trying to give the ring structure on $H^*(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ using group cohomology techniques. So far, I have found that:
$$H^n(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} \quad n=0 \\ \mathbb{Z}^2 \,\,\,n=1 \\ \mathbb{Z} \,\,\,\,\, n=2 \\ 0 \quad n \ge 3.\end{cases}$$
So, I believe that I can let $a,b$ be generators of degree $1$ and $c$ a generator of degree $2$, in which case the ring structure I am after will be of the form $\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c]/(\text{some relations})$.
Some of the relations are obvious: we should have $ac=bc=c^2=0$ since these all land in spaces of degree $\ge 3$, which have $0$ cohomology (I am writing $ab$ for $a \smile b$, the cup product).
My final relation must then relate $ab$ with $c$. I have no idea how to go about this - it would be pretty nice if $ab$ was a generator for $H^2$ so that I could get rid of $c$ but I am not sure how to proceed.
For the sake of clarification I will also write the definition of cup product I am using: if $[u] \in H^p(G,M)$ and $[v] \in H^q(G,N)$ then I define $u \smile v \in C^{p+q}(G,M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} N)$ by:
$$(u \smile v)(g_1,\ldots,g_{p+q})=(-1)^{pq}u(g_1,\ldots,g_p) \otimes g_1\cdots g_p v(g_{p+1},\ldots,g_{p+q}).$$

Since you want to use a cochain definition of the cup product, have you tried writing down cocycle representatives of your generators?
